# WordPress Post in new format

Tags: plugins

As you know, the following code publishes the latest content in a group in its WordPress

```
<?php
            $my_query = new WP_Query('showposts=1&cat=172');
            while ($my_query->have_posts()):
            $my_query->the_post();
            $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;
            ?>
```

I want to make changes to this code so the last article in a group is not displayed and the pre-final content of the same group will be displayed. thank u

Comment: I'm not sure there's an easy way to test if this is the last iteration of the loop. You could try and get a counter first to track it, or write the_post into a buffer and echo it in the next iteration, but neither of those seem great to me. How would this work with paging?

Comment: And what do you mean "the pre-final content" ?

Comment: tnx. "pre-final" means "one before the last"

Comment: Please write your suggested code